# slow response website windows server 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, windows-server

website getting slow which is running windows server 2008  built using .net framework 4.0 .
my question ,is it  DNS problem  because when i check dns.exe it is consume about 5.4GB. Are we under DDos attack?.
If i run the website using VS 2012 inside the server ,it is running and response fast, but when i try to use it  as client then no response just keep loading for long time. we have tried to find the problems but no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a check via cmd and checking net state
you can do it with netstate -a -n ans se how many request you have 
checking also sql port and your rdp port

for safe porpouse check with your hosting provider too.

Answer (score 1):

You may be noticing the effects of eDNS (a new DNS protocol extension) being enabled by default in 2008 r2. It tries to do some additional stuff which builds up the RAM usage over the course of time.

Try disabling eDNS in 2008 r2 and observe.

**`prompt>  dnscmd /config /EnableEDnsProbes 0`**

you can also set this registry key to 0.

1. go to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DNS\Parameters
2. A new DWORD called EnableEDnsProbes needs to be created and set to 0.

just to be safe, restart the DNS service.